# Enable sinon fakeServer logs

Tags: javascript, testing, mocking, automated-tests, sinon

I'm running several tests where I'm mocking http calls using sinon fake server:

```
import sinon from 'sinon';
...
const fakeServer = sinon.fakeServer.create();
fakeServer.respondWith('POST', '/myapp/myendpoint/pathparam', [201, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, myPayload]);
...
```

However the fake server is returning a not found error: `[404, {  }, (empty string)]`.

I cannot figure out what's going wrong.

Is there any way to activate some kind of logs that tells me what is going on?

After going over [sinon's documentation](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/fake-xhr-and-server/), I cannot find anything about logs or debug flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inspecting `sinon` I found that it does not contain the fake server but it is exposing  `nise/fake-server/`.

Then I went over `nise` and I ended up finding that method to trace the behaviour:

```
logger: function () {
    // no-op; override via configure()
},
```

So to enable logs in the fake-server the only thing you need to do is to specify a behaviour when you create the fake server:

```
fakeServer = sinon.fakeServer.create({logger: str => console.log('Fake server', str)});
```